# Where should I list the header in c and makefile

Tags: c, makefile, header-files

I'm learning how to split up my C codes into multiple files. What I don't quite get is where must I specify the header files. If I understand correctly, a function's header file must be listed in

1. the source file of the function, using `#include`,
2. any code that calls the function, using `#include`, and
3. `Makefile`, as a dependency for every file that `#include` the header file.

This just seems so redundant to me. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I would suggest trying a smarter build system, like cmake. It will figure out your dependency tree for you. Especially since you're just getting started, don't spend your time learning make.

Comment: To be clear, at least for C, cmake isn't figuring anything out. It is using the compiler's information to do that (but does so automatically). You can do it manually (as the link in my answer talks about) or use any of the systems that do it automatically, like cmake or the autotools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking I don't believe it **needs** to be in the source file with the function but I believe you will get warnings with many common compiler flags if you don't. (Also I could be wrong about this.)

You absolutely need it in other files that use the function so that the compiler can know what the signature of the function is correctly (it has to guess otherwise and it **will** guess wrong and make mistakes because of that). Things might still work but that isn't guaranteed or a good thing to count on.

You need it listed in the makefile so that make knows that it needs to rebuild the object file if the header file changes (the dependency on the source file is implicit in the rule itself generally but the header files aren't part of that). Listing all of this manually in the makefile is tedious which is why compilers help you do this and why things like the autotools (and other such frameworks) automate much of that for you. See [Advanded Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/autodep.html) for some discussion of this.

In short, no, you aren't missing anything but it isn't as annoying as you think it is either.

Answer (score 1):

Actually only 2. is really necessary as foreign code obviously needs to see the function declaration.

1. might be needed if you have additional declarations besides function prototypes that you want to make available to both foreign and defining translation units. Of course this also ensures that prototypes within header and source file agree.

Assuming a GNU-compatible toolchain, you do not need to list header dependencies manually in 3., but auto-generate them on compilation via `-MMD` or similar and include the generated files via

```
-include $(DEPS)
```

where `DEPS` is something like `$(wildcard *.d)` or `$(OBJECTS:%.o=%.d)`, depending on how exactly you structure your makefile.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid redundancy you may group multiple header files of functions that are likely to be used together in a single header:

```
/* file foofuncs.h */
#include <foo.h>
#include <foo2.h>
[...]
```

And then include only the umbrella header:

```
#include <foofuncs.h>
```

And add a target for it in the Makefile:

```
foofuncs.h: foo.h foo2.h [...]
    touch foofuncs.h
cippa.o: cippa.c foofuncs.h
lippa.o: lippa.c foofuncs.h bar.h [...]
```

On small enough projects I use a single unbrella header for the whole program.

Comment: I'm not sure that make bit works correctly. Nothing updates the timestamp on `foofuncs.h` in that so even if `foo.h` changes I'm not sure `cippa.o` will rebuild because of it. (But I'd have to test this to be sure.)

Comment: Answering @Etan: My fault, I wrote just the headings of targets for brevity, but didn't make it clear. Now I'll edit.